# Why CFLAGS not working with pip in Windows

Tags: setuptools, distutils, pyhook

This is about Windows!
I have a modern LLVM setup to work with distutils via `compiler=mingw32` option in config file.
But newer clang versions are more strict with warnings, so I want to pass `-Wno-error=int-conversion` via CFLAGS to install multidict in python 3.12.
so I kindly use:

```
$env:CFLAGS="-Wno-error=int-conversion"
pip install multidict
```

But it fails and clearly the gcc command do not include CFLAGS.
It looks like distutils/setuptools bug. Any alternative to workaround this?